# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hypothesis' when running pytest

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I'm running  `pytest` and returns  `ERROR  - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hypothesis'`

I am using a virtual linux server, in a conda env with python version 3.7.12

I tried `pip install hypothesis` and `conda install -c conda-forge hypothesis`

The installation were both successful but it doesn't change the fact that when I re-run `pytest` it outputs the same error.

I saw there are similar questions and some answers below talked about different python versions (but I didn't figure out the solution to my problem from the posts).

```
(conda_env) [user@hpc02 user]$ python -V
Python 3.7.12

(conda_env) [user@hpc02 ~]$ pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.8, pytest-6.2.3, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/user
plugins: anyio-2.2.0
collected 0 items / 1 error
```

I'm not sure why it's python 3.8.8 in test session but when I check python version it's 3.7.12, and whether it might be related to the error, and if so, how I could resolve it.

Really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Edit: Thank you for your help! I was running pytest as a test step of installing a package via `pip install sinto`, I just realized that they require python 3.8, so I created another python3.8 conda env and did `pip install hypothesis` then run `pytest`, now it's popping up another `ValueError` so I guess this `ModuleNotFoundError` is magically resolved... (to conclude I guess the problem lies with pytest requires 3.8 but my python is 3.7 so there is some kind of conflict that avoided detection of hypothesis file...?)

Comment: 2 possible problems: 1. You are calling the "hypothesis" somewhere, but you forgot to import 2. You have multi environments in Anaconda, when you install your library you didn't install it in your working environment

Comment: if test uses `Python 3.8.8` to run it then maybe you should install it again using `python3.7 -m pip install pytest` and maybe it will run with `python3.7`. OR you could open `pytest` in text editor and it may have line like `#!/usr/bin/python3.8` which you can change to `#!/usr/bin/python3.7`. OR you should check if you can run `python3.7 -m pytest`

Comment: Thanks! I thought it's automatic that when I install something without prior setting to adjust working environment, it's supposed to be installing in the previous operating conda env or my current working environment...?

Comment: I don't know - I never use conda

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
python -V
```

If you have more than one version of Python set up on your computer, installing a package using pip could end up placing the files in a different location than the one you intend to use it in.

Comment: Thanks, I built a conda env for it so it shouldn't have been messed up... btw the python -V returns 3.7.12